# Access localhost from the internet

Tags: localhost, port, wamp, portforwarding

I need to forward my localhost for a short period of time for testing purposes. It has to be accessed from the public internet.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't that belong on ServerFault?

Comment: You cannot forward your localhost any more than you as a person can "forward" your self identity to someone else.  Please explain what actual functionality you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED If you think a question is off topic, flag it and a moderator can move it to the right site

Comment: if you don't want to use third-party software and have your own SSH server then you can use TCP tunneling with SSH for exposing the localhost. See here https://nspointers.com/programming/expose-localhost/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You go into your router configuration and forward port 80 to the LAN IP of the computer running the web server.

Then anyone outside your network (but not you inside the network) can access your site using your WAN IP address ([whatismyipcom](http://www.whatismyip.com)).

Comment: >Then anyone outside your network (but not you inside the network) can access your site... Can you explain why please? I don't understand it, can't loopbacks be handled?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a network guy, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: How can you also make it accessible inside network?

Comment: Use the computer's LAN IP inside the network (http://192.168.x.x).

Comment: Setting up Port-Forwarding from my router worked for me. I thought I was going do some ssh kung-fu but it was actually quite simple from the web UI of my router.

Comment: This will not be application if the user;s network is under CGNAT.

Comment: Can I do ip forward to port 80 without accessing the router configurations?

Comment: I think this doesn't work all the time. Tunneling seems the better choice

Answer (score 302):

There are a couple of good free services that let you do the same. Ideal for showing something quickly during development/testing:

- http://localtunnel.me/
- https://ngrok.com/
- http://localhost.run/
- [Cloudflare Tunnel](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/share-new-site/)
- [btunnel](https://www.btunnel.in)

Comment: + https://serveo.net

Comment: Thanks! localhost.run worked for me, while localtunnel.me didn't but maybe there is an issue on my side or system. Saw the 'pricing' wording on the ngrok site so didn't try it.

Comment: Used localhost.run.. I'm able to expose port 3000 not just the specified 8080. Thanks

Comment: Recently learned about https://tunnelin.com which can be added to your list. Also, http://localtunnel.me/ not working anymore.

Comment: I'm trying localhost.run but every time it generates a URL for me, I go to the URL, then in the CMD  it shows closed by remote host. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use ngrok or similar tools https://blog.cyble.com/2021/02/15/ngrok-platform-abused-by-hackers-to-deliver-a-new-wave-of-phishing-attacks/

Comment: Huge + for Cloudflare Tunnel option.

Comment: Hi, I wrote an article on setting a tunnel using Cloudflared. I hope it helps:
https://blog.continium-labs.com/how-to-connect-to-local-development-server-from-internet/

Comment: [btunnel](https://www.btunnel.in) is a nice option as well.

Answer (score 6):

Even though you didn't provide enough information to answer this question properly, your best shots are [SSH tunnels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) (or reverse SSH tunnels).

You only need one SSH server on your internal or remote network to provide access to your local machine.

You can use PUTTY (it has a GUI) on Windows to create your tunnel.

Answer (score 3):

use your ip address or a service like [noip.com](https://www.noip.com) if you need something more practical. Then eventually configure your router properly so incoming connection will be forwarded to the machine with the server running.

Answer (score -2):

You are accesing `localhost`, meaning you have a web server running on your machine. To access it from Internet, you need to assign a public IP address to your machine. Then you can access `http://<public_ip>:<port>/`. Port number is normally 80.

Comment: Yeah, but the telecoms always block port 80 for residential consumers

Comment: Its much easier to use ngork but url is not fixed

Answer (score -12):

Try with your IP Address , I think you can access it by internet.

Comment: Most likely, his IP address will be a local network one, so behind a router and/or firewall, and not directly accessible by internet. He needs to expose his local server to the public internet over a tunnel.