# How to share localhost

Tags: localhost, webserver, publishing

I have one noob question. I want to share with my friends my web-app project. I don't have my own server, so is there a way to share localhost, that someone on another computer can take a look on my local-site?

Comment: You have many ways to do this, you can use port forwarding with Dynamic DNS or use proxy, VPN, or tunneling. Each technique has its own pros and cons - read this article where the author compares these methods https://tunnelin.com/expose-local-web-server

Comment: You can use `ngrok`, which is a platform that will forward your local ports on the internet. You can find more information on https://ngrok.com/

Comment: https://pinggy.io is one of the easiest way to share localhost. However there are other methods depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve this via port-forwarding.  This question should help.

[Access localhost from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet)

You will probably need to replace port 80 mentioned here with whatever port your localhost server is serving on.  I am assuming you are attempting to do this using something like Visual Studio or Angular-CLI to serve this up?

Comment: Im creating web-app using angular2 with CLI.

Comment: Yea just forward the port that it serves up on to your local machine from the router and give your friends the public IP address