# Connect to website deployed on local machine from anywhere on internet

Tags: networking, ip, localhost, port

I have hosted a ASP.Net website on my localhost within my organisation. I want to connect to this website from any system around the world. I am unable to access it for now. What things should be done to allow access to the website to everyone in the Internet.

Comment: I would highly, highly recommend against even trying to open your local organisation to the world. Highly. You should look into getting an actual server infrastructure; there's a reason they exist. I am not a `.net` guy, but I would imagine you should look into Azure Cloud or something like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access localhost from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet)

Comment: I agree with @MattFletcher, but given your question my answer below is the best I can give.

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong, but even beside the question of _should you_, I think it only really touches on the tip of the iceberg. There are a lot of things you'd have to do to make the site accessible beyond opening firewalls, such as various server config to accept your public IP rather than `localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required port(s) need to be opened in all firewalls that are between your web server and the internet.

This can include both software firewall(s) on your server, i.e. `firewalld`, and hardware firewalls in place as network middleware.