# Implementing and testing Facebook comment Plugins locally

Tags: spring, facebook, tomcat, virtualhost, facebook-comments

I am working on a web project using  spring, hibernate. i am hosting it on local host using tomcat server. i want to add a face book comment plugin to my website. is it possible to test face book comment plugin locally ? How ?
i am unable to make virtual domain for hosting.

Comment: is your problem (in general) [Acces localhost from internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108539/592355) ? ..then, this answer helps.

Comment: No, that is not possible. The URLs you point the comment plugin to need to be publicly reachable via HTTP(S), and I think you need a domain name too (using an address with an IP instead should not work either.)