# How to connect to minikube exposed Nodeport from other computers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to expose one of my applications running on `minikube` to outer world. I have already used a `Nodeport` and I can access the application within the same hist machine using a web browser.

But I need to expose this application to one of my friends who is living somewhere far, so he can see it in his browser too.

This is how my `deployment.yaml` files look like, should I use an Ingress or how can I do this using an `ingress` ?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
        name: node-web-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
            name: node-web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # you can specify any labels you want here
              name: node-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-web-app
        # image must be the same as you built before (name:tag)
        image: banuka/node-web-app
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        imagePullPolicy: Never
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

**How can I expose this deployment which is running a `nodejs` server to outside world?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access localhost from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet)

Comment: Hey, I've voted to close as a duplicate and linked to another question (which was closed). This isn't really a k8s issue, it's about accessing your computer from the internet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet.

Answer (score -1):

You generally can’t. The networking is set up only for the host machine. You could probably use ngrok or something though?

Comment: This is a commercial tool, not open-source, so this is basically advertising. I'm pretty sure I don't really like that.

Comment: Ngrok? It used to be open source for sure, I guess in the last rewrite the made it a product?

Comment: It says that v1 isn't maintained or even working, and is closed-source in v2. On the github page I just checked: https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok

Comment: Looks like there's a few forks/clones but nothing directly comparable with a hosted server component. Such is the way of things I suppose.

Comment: I think Rio from Rancher does something similar but from the cloud rather than your personal laptop. That's probably a lot more secure anyway.

Comment: No? Rio is a PaaS framework. Ngrok is a service/tool for setting up a reverse tunnel for something on your localhost. FOSS or not, it's the standard tool for the space.

Comment: Standard is a strong word :) I've been in the industry a long time and have always understand ssh-tunnelling to be the standard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngrok`. For example

```
ngrok http 8000
```

This will generate piblicly accessable url.

Comment: This is a commercial tool, not open-source, so this is basically advertising. I'm pretty sure I don't really like that.

Comment: This is free tool to certain extend and totally usable in such case.

Comment: No, that's definitely a commercial tool, based on a freemium model with a very limited 'free' tier. The standard approach to this problem is to use ssh (to create an ssh-tunnel), a ubiquitous free tool in most operating systems. I'm always open to a learning experience though, so if you wouldn't mind expanding on that @tefozi I'd love to know how it's not commercial? https://ngrok.com/

Comment: if that is one time thing and for testing purposes, ngrok will do its job

Comment: what does that have to do with advertising commercial tools on stack-overflow when there's a perfectly good free and open solution that is more common?

Comment: That particular feature that is free. Nobody cares that this tool is commercial. I proposed solution that will definitely work.