# Cannot connect to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, firewall, windows-firewall

I installed Jenkins on my windows server and it works when accessing it from localhost:8080.

When I try to access it from outside the server like `serveripaddress:8080` it's not accessible.

There is a inbound rule in firewall to named `Jenkins` for port `8080` for java.
[image]

running `netstat`:
[image]

Any idea what can I do in order to be able to access it from outside the server?

Browsing to localhost:8080/manage there is an alert:
`It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.`

Comment: try doing a telnet to the ip and port and see if this is established? 
telnet IP 8080 
Also, where is the server located?

Comment: @SurendraDeshpande
I checked using this https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
and it says port 8080 is closed...

Comment: where is the server hosted?

Comment: @SurendraDeshpande in our local area.

Comment: Not on any cloud provider? What does local area mean? on prem data center?

Comment: @SurendraDeshpande Not on a cloud, on a local server.

Comment: you mean on your local machine?

Comment: @SurendraDeshpande yes

Comment: thats not how it works, when you are trying to access jenkins or any other service from your local machine using a public IP. You will have to do a port forwarding. 
Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108483/access-localhost-from-the-internet and this should help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear in your question whether you had set up a firewall rule on your local computer or the server.

Make sure you have opened inbound port 8080 on TCP on your servers firewall.

To make sure the firewall is not the issue, you could test by turning off the firewall completley, assuming the server is not exposed to the web.

Comment: I think it is a firewall related issue, but there is an inbound rule already for port 8080, I will attach a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Final solution: open port 8080 TCP for any program

If I tried to limit it to jenkins.exe or Jenkins service, it would not allow connections. Not sure why.

Comment: The port in my server was open but not at the company that hosts our servers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. The default windows firewall rule for Jenkins that gets created (named "Jenkins") is a firewall rule to allow for port 8080 if the application is a specific match. By default when using the MSI installer, the path to the JDK/JRE has a double slash "\\" pointing to the location of the java environment. If you edit the firewall rule to turn the double slash into a single, it works just fine.